# Retag request: on SuperUser, rename external-harddrive to external-hard-drive

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

HDD-related tags on SuperUser:

- hard-drive (291)
- external-harddrive (91)
- internal-harddrive (6)
- network-hard-drive (1)
- hard-drive-failure (28)
- hard-drive-image (2)

I think the dash-enabled `hard-drive` is a good standard, so this request is for moving

- `external-harddrive` to `external-hard-drive`
- `internal-harddrive` to `internal-hard-drive`

**Edit**: Actually, I don't see much reason for keeping a separate `internal-hard-drive` tag.  It should probably be merged with `hard-drive`.

**Edit 2**: Bump.  This has gotten the `status-completed` tag, but I'm not seeing any changes.  Does this mean the request was confusing, or should it have gotten a `status-declined`?

Comment: How do you buy it instore?

Comment: i think of them as HDDs -- Hard Disk Drives.  the "disk" is superfluous, thus "hard-drive".  NewEgg lists them as "Hard Drives": http://www.newegg.com/Store/Category.aspx?Category=15&name=Hard-Drives

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>internal-hardrive</kbd> merged with <kbd>hard-drive</kbd>
<kbd>network-hard-drive</kbd> merged with <kbd>hard-drive</kbd>

I don't see a need to change the others. The <kbd>external-harddrive</kbd> change requires the tag to be created, and since it is already commonly used I am not 100% convinced that it needs to be changed at this stage.

Comment: you could create it by simply editing one `external-harddrive` instance to the new version, if that's what's needed.  it's one of those tags that will keep cropping up in either form, and the lesser used form occasionally gets edited by hand to the more populated form.  i requested the change because i personally think it's more consistent with other tags using the term "hard-drive".

Comment: thx for moving the others, tho. :)

Comment: Understood. However for the moment I am leaving it as is. We try and avoid create tags that are to long, as these can also cause problems.

Comment: seems like serverfault prefers `external-hdd`, is that preferable?  i don't like long tags either, but we're talking one additional character.

Comment: I'll investigate further and check with the other SU moderators. If they all agree will make the chance